# How to display YUV image without RGB conversion?

Tags: c#, wpf, rgb, yuv

My desktop application receives YUV-images (YUV4:2:0 YV12 to be exact) it need to display. I convert it to RGB and create BitmapSource out of it, which I then display. But this conversion isn't fast enough for my application, despite me using unsafe code with integer-only operations and right shifts instead of divisions (formulae taken here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917087.aspx).

So: is there a way to display YUV-images without prior RGB-conversion? Some control I don't know of? Some hardware-accelerated converter maybe?

Comment: The display will of course be totally wrong, but have you tried rendering the YUV images directly (as if they were RGB), to see if it's fast enough? If you remove the conversion completely and it's still too slow then rendering it in native YUV won't help, obviously.

Comment: I'm using the Y-plane as a 8bpp grayscale bitmap and it works fine. But I need colors...

Comment: For video APIs it's typical to display YUV, without RGB conversion step. In your case however it's the conversion which is too slow. [Color Converter DSP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819079) is pretty fast, you might want to mount it into your code for the the conversion step.